# nodejs - Why does setInterval suddenly stop working?

Tags: node.js, docker, setinterval

I have a very simple setInterval NodeJS script:

`server.js`:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Up and running...');
}, 60*1000);
```

I run it with `nodemon` in Docker (files below).

My problem is that `setInterval` this script sporadically stops working with absolutely no error message, no exception, no signs of whatever. Nodemon is running, my script is seemingly running, but setInterval does not 'tick' anymore.

This happens randomly, usually after days or weeks of runtime.

This happened to me on differnt projects, different servers, however all Docker, all Node 10.8 and all Debian 10.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10.8.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install nodemon -g

CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  node:
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following issue on github sounds pretty similar to your problem: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149

Try upgrading to node `>=v10.9.0` as the fix should be included in this or higher versions.

Comment: @adamsfamily: I guess I have to wait a few weeks until I get an upvote/accept? :)

Comment: Accepted as an answer. I confirm that my timers hang exactly after 25 days and I'm running Node 10.8. Upgrading to 10.9 soon and will come back here if it didn't help :) Thanks a lot for the link you shared!